RestTemplate- How to decide maxConnection and maxConnectionPerRoute?
In RestTemplate how do we decide what should be maxConnection and maxConnectionPerRoute value?
In some examples i see maxConnection = 100 and maxConnectionPerRoute = 20 and other value. Why can't i set both values to big number like 1000.
What factors will impact if i set big numbers to both of them. I explored many answers but couldn't convince myself yet.
If possible Please provide me some better resources to find the answers if explaining that much detail is not possible.
